# Is it possible to insert PostgreSql table using Postman?

Tags: java, postgresql, post, postman

I have a PostgreSQL database running on Docker container on 5434 port. I am wondering if it would be possible to send POST request and insert data for the following table?

```
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Integer age;
}
```

If it is not, what would you suggest to insert random data to PostgreSql database via pgAdmin or any proper way?

Answer (score 0):

[Postman](https://www.postman.com/) is a REST, SOAP, and GraphQL API client. It can not work with a PostgreSQL server directly. One of the many [PostgreSQL clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) should be used for this.

However there are solutions to translate your database to API. You can checkout:

- [PostgREST](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/) if you into REST
- [PostGraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/) if you like GraphQL API.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I am not sure if I could explain what I was looking for. I need a tool in order to insert data to PostgreSQL database like Postman, by creating a POST configuration and setting field values randomly e.g. `{{ randımInteger }}`, `{{ randomString }}`... Then I just click POST request and each request will create a record using this random string or integer values. Is that possible?

Comment: So you may use one of the  PostgreSQL clients mentioned in the answer to use SQL to insert data, or you can install PostgREST (even on your local PC) that would connect to your PostgreSQL database. You then be able to send POST requests to the PostgREST server, that would in turn translate your request to PostgreSQL database.

Comment: So, there are many on that list. Which one would you suggest to me? PostgREST only? Or any other?

Comment: If you choose to use PosgreSQL client, I would suggest using pgAdmin or DBeaver. If you need simply insert some data - pgAdmin will be easier to learn. DBeaver is my choice in everyday work because it has many useful features the pgAdmin lacks.

Comment: Actually I have both of them installed my PC and experience at pgAdmin. But, do you mean to use create script? I meant to insert using an easier way like in Postman? Because if I use create script, I have to update values on each run of this script.

Comment: yes, you may create a SQL script, that inserts random values to your tables.

Comment: I already know this. Do you mean to use something like `INSERT INTO public.student(id, email, name) VALUES (100, 'fred@gmail.com', 'Fred');` for hours? I already know that, but I need a smarter way to automatize things. In this approach, are you **aware of** that I have to update the values on each running?

Comment: To insert something random, you can use PostgreSQL function [random()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html), like 'INSERT INTO public.student(id, email, name) SELECT rnd, rnd::text||'@gmail.com', rnd::text FROM trunc(random()*1000) as rnd;'  If you want to insert data automatically, you can use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) tool.

Comment: Sorry, but I was looking for completely a different approach instead of updating sql or using random in sql.